# Generic DAO Setup using Spring, JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to make a generic code that implements some of the most common operations on any entity. I have used Spring Initializr to generate the base of the product using Gradle, Spring Boot 2.1.0 SNAPSHOT, JPA and Hibernate. I created the schema and tables using MySQL Workbench and used that to generate the entities for my project. So coming to the actual issue, I tried to create a generic DAO where some of the common operations like findbyid, edit, delete, create, update, getall would be implemented and then extend it to other DAO classes to promote reusability and make the work faster. So here is the code I have till now:

**UserController.java**:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public UserEntity getUser() throws Exception {
        userService.getUser();
    }
}
```

**UserService.java**:

```
public interface UserService {
    UsersEntity getUser();
}
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserDAO userDAO;

    @Transactional
    public UsersEntity getUser() {
        return userDAO.find(Long.valueOf("123"));
    }
}
```

**UserDAO.java**:

```
public interface UserDAO extends GenericRepositoryInterface<UsersEntity> {
}
```

**UserDAOImpl.java**:

```
@Repository
public abstract class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
}
```

**GenericRepositoryInterface.java**:

```
public interface GenericRepositoryInterface<T> {
    T save(T emp);
    Boolean delete(T emp);
    T edit(T emp);
    T find(Long empId);
}
```

**GenericRepositoryImplementation.java**:

```
@Repository
public class GenericRepositoryImplementation<T> implements GenericRepositoryInterface<T> {

    protected EntityManager entityManager;
    private T type;

    public GenericRepositoryImplementation(T type) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.type = type;
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public T save(T emp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        entityManager.persist(emp);
        entityManager.flush();
        return emp;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean delete(T emp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            entityManager.remove(emp);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public T edit(T emp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            return entityManager.merge(emp);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T find(Long empId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (T) entityManager.find(type.getClass(), empId);
    }
}
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong with the implementation but whenever I run the application, it crashes with the below logs:

```
2018-06-24 18:12:14.748 DEBUG 72491 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : Application failed to start due to an exception

        org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.test.dao.UserDAO' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1350) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:580) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1350) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:580) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1222) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.example.test.Application.main(Application.java:11) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]

        2018-06-24 18:12:14.749 ERROR 72491 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

        ***************************
        APPLICATION FAILED TO START
        ***************************

        Description:

        Field userDAO in com.example.test.service.impl.UserServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.example.test.dao.UserDAO' that could not be found.


        Action:

        Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.test.dao.UserDAO' in your configuration.
```

I am not sure why, but there is a UserDAO class present in the mentioned location and it is not recognising it. Have I missed any annotations or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No implementation for `UserDAO` was found.

You want to extends your generic DAO implementation:

```
@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl extends GenericRepositoryImplementation< UsersEntity> implements UserDAO {
     public UserDaoImpl() {
          super(UsersEntity.class);
     }
}
```

Your generic DAO implementation should accept a class of type `<T>` instead of an instance of `T`:

```
public class GenericRepositoryImplementation<T> implements GenericRepositoryInterface<T> {

    protected EntityManager entityManager;
    private Class<T> type;

    public GenericRepositoryImplementation(Class<T> type) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! I totally ignored the issue that I was using an abstract class and the extends was not done properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your UserDAOImpl. 
Here you are trying to inject dependency of an abstract class. provide concrete class for userDao and then inject it to your controller/Service.